# Получить рандомные значения из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Ребят, как правильно составить запрос?

Есть таблица. В ней, допустим, 100 записей. Как получить 10 рандомных записей. Изпользую PHP и MySql. Проблема с составлением запроса.

Двигаюсь в таком направлении:

```
Select * random(10) From table
```

Comment: Нужно всегда получать десять разных записей?

Comment: На самом деле, выборка случайных записей не самая лёгкая задача, если нужно выполнить её эффективно. `order by rand()`, как известно, выполняется слишком медленно. Неплохое решение, на мой взгляд, описано в этой статье: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/ , но я его не проверял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select * from table order by rand() limit 0,10;
```

Comment: почему 0,10 а не 10???

Answer (score 0):

Самый, скажем так, очевидный вариант

```
<?php
$id = rand(1, 100);
$sql = "SELECT * from `table` where `id` = $rand");
/*
some code
*/
?>
```

А так, достаточно долго и нудно этот вопрос разбирали на киберфоруме, [ссылка на тему](http://www.sql.ru/forum/207212/poluchenie-sluchaynoy-zapisi-zapisey-iz-tablicy)

Comment: А 10? В цикле крутить?

Comment: @ua6xh проблемка, не предусмотрел.